# Cordova plugin listening to device orientation change. Is it possible?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I try hard to develop plugin which can listen to orientation change to proceed necessary changes without essential added javascript code or necessity to edit activity java code.

There are option to use orientationChangeListener, but I need only listen to switching between portrait and landscape modes, not heading of device. This is usable, but too much monstrous for this little task.

Are there any other options to resolve it? Is it possible to modify onConfigurationChanged method of main activity or create some new onCofigurationChange listener?
Or in a fact CordovaPlugin doesn't know what is happening around him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution to this (thanks to Andrew Grieve at Cordova mailing list), so I post it here, if somebody will have similar problem. Key is onLayoutChangeListener of view (WebView or other view, if plugin add any).
Put below code inside some method of plugin:

```
webView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight,
            int oldBottom) {
        // some code
    }
});
```

However, there is one big BUT. This listener is available in API11+, so do not function on Android 2.2 or 2.3...

Answer (score 2):

Your Cordova plugin requires writing of both Javascript and Java code. Being as your'e going to be writing Javascript anyway wouldn't this suffice?

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {

   if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {

    // landscape view

    } else {
        // portrait view
    }

}, false);
```

Comment: I don't know, if some Javascript code is needed, I plan that plugin without Javascript code (and with look at plugin.xml, this is possible) controlled by config.xml prefrences. (And if it needed, I can make blank Javascript code of course.) Your code surely works, but is not effective, because Java Cordova interface call Javascript orientation change event, and then Javascript call essential Java code. There are pointeless call over the bridge between Java and webView when there Javascript code isn't really needen. (I hope)

Comment: Well if you don't want to use Javascript, maybe you should'nt use Cordova.

Comment: Huh, I think question is clear, so I don't understand, why there are any Javascript mention. I ask on better and elegant solution.